# get json from php error

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a problem: I try to get a value from php json but I get an error. This is my syntax:

```
<select name='posting_daerah' id='optionDaerah' class='form'>
    <?php
        $dataDaerah=mysql_query("SELECT*FROM t_daerah");
        while($d=mysql_fetch_array($dataDaerah)){
            echo"<option value='$d[daerah_id]'>$d[daerah_nama]</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#optionDaerah').change(function(){
            var daerah_value=$(this).val();
            alert(daerah_value);
            var data ="{daerah:"+daerah_value+"}";
            $.ajax({
                    type    : "post",
                    url     : "get_lokasi",
                    data    : data,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {                                  
                        $.each(function(index){
                            alert(index);
                        });
                    },
                    error: function(xhr,textStatus,err) {
                        console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
                        console.log("responseText: "+ xhr.responseText);
                        console.log("status: " + xhr.status);
                        console.log("text status: " + textStatus);
                        console.log("error: " + err);
                    }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to search data from `id='optionDaerah'`. This is my php (get_lokasi) code:

```
<?php
    $daerah=isset($_POST['daerah'])?$_POST['daerah']:1;

    $data=mysql_query("SELECT*FROM t_lokasi WHERE daerah_id='$daerah' ")or die(mysql_error());

    $arr=array();
    while($a=mysql_fetch_array($data)){
        array_push($arr,$a['lokasi_nama']);

    }

    echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

I got an error from console:

```
readyState: 4 
status: 200 (index):125
text status: parsererror (index):126
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: You should separate your SQL statements like `SELECT*FROM` to this `SELECT * FROM`

Comment: ^ beat me to it. i would put a space before or too, same line.

Comment: i think that isn't the wrong code

Comment: Yeah, It isn't. You should look at your network tab on developer tools to see what server's returning. There will be the error that jquery thinks that is the json, but it's invalid. I hope i was clear.

Comment: You need to read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) so you don’t create any more severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) like the ones you have here. Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and is a safer way to compose queries. `$_POST` data **never** goes directly in a query.